# Identifying "clusters" or "groups" in a matrix

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix, cluster-computing

I have a matrix that is populated with discrete elements, and I need to cluster them into intact groups. So, for example, take this matrix:

```
[A B B C A]
[A A B A A]
[A B B C C]
[A A A A A]
```

There would be two separate clusters for A, two separate clusters for C, and one cluster for B.

The output I'm looking for would ideally assign a unique ID to each clister, something like this:

```
[1 2 2 3 4]
[1 1 2 4 4]
[1 2 2 5 5]
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

Right now I have an R code that does this recursively by just iteratively checking nearest neighbor, but it quickly overflows when the matrix gets large (i.e., 100x100).

Is there a built in function in R that can do this? I looked into raster and image processing, but no luck. I'm convinced it must be out there.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See also [some discussion about cross posting etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/254929)

Comment: Just to be obsessive: do diagonal contacts (distance = sqrt(2) rather than 1) count as being in the same cluster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could approach this by building a lattice graph representing your matrix, where edges are only retained if the vertices have the same type:

```
# Build initial matrix and lattice graph
library(igraph)
mat <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1), nrow=4)
labels <- as.vector(mat)
g <- graph.lattice(dim(mat))
lyt <- layout.auto(g)

# Remove edges between elements of different types
edgelist <- get.edgelist(g)
retain <- labels[edgelist[,1]] == labels[edgelist[,2]]
g <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[!retain])

# Take a look at what we have
plot(g, layout=lyt)
```

[image]

Vertices are numbered going down columns. It's easy to see that all we need to do is grab the components of this graph:

```
matrix(clusters(g)$membership, nrow=nrow(mat))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    2    3    4
# [2,]    1    1    2    4    4
# [3,]    1    2    2    5    5
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

If you wanted to include diagonals in the lattice, you might start with a lattice with neighborhood size 2 and then limit to elements that are no more than one row or one column apart. Consider the following matrix:

```
[A B C B]
[B A A A]
```

Here's the code that will capture 4 groups, not 6, due to including diagonal links:

```
# Build initial matrix and lattice graph (neighborhood size 2)
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), nrow=2)
labels <- as.vector(mat)
rows <- (seq(length(labels)) - 1) %% nrow(mat)
cols <- ceiling(seq(length(labels)) / nrow(mat))
g <- graph.lattice(dim(mat), nei=2)

# Remove edges between elements of different types or that aren't diagonal
edgelist <- get.edgelist(g)
retain <- labels[edgelist[,1]] == labels[edgelist[,2]] &
  abs(rows[edgelist[,1]] - rows[edgelist[,2]]) <= 1 &
  abs(cols[edgelist[,1]] - cols[edgelist[,2]]) <= 1
g <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[!retain])

# Cluster to obtain final groups
matrix(clusters(g)$membership, nrow=nrow(mat))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    1    1    1
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. One additional question (seeing as I have no familiarity with the igraph package) is there a quick way to get the group size for each unique group without looping? So with the example, the group sizes would be: Group 1=9, Group 2=5, Group 3=1, Group 4=3, and Group 5=2

Comment: @user3037237 you could use `table(clusters(g)$membership)` or `clusters(g)$csize`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure whether this answers the same problem, but I recently wrote some code which groups wall segments in a maze in the same manner, i.e. nearest-neighbor.  Mine is iterative, and makes use of the dist() function.   Here's some of the code I used.

I start with a N*4 matrix containing all the wall segments (generated using Prim's Tree Alg); the columns being (x0,y0,x1,y1) defining the endpoints of a given segment.  All segments start and end on integer grid points and are of length 1.  Each element of `treelist` contains all clustered segments.  For the question posted, this should be a little easier because each item has only one coordinate (row,column) rather than two.

```
treelist<-list()
 treecnt<-1
 #kill edge walls, i.e. wall segments on the border of the maze.
 #  edges<- which(dowalls[,1]==dowalls[,3] | dowalls[,2]==dowalls[,4])
 vedges <- which( (dowalls[,1]==dowalls[,3]) & (dowalls[,1]==1 | dowalls[,1]==dimx+1) )
 hedges <- which( (dowalls[,2]==dowalls[,4]) & (dowalls[,2]==1 | dowalls[,1]==dimy+1) )
 dowalls<-dowalls[-c(vedges,hedges),,drop=FALSE]
 # now sort into trees 
 while(nrow(dowalls)>0 ) {
     tree <- matrix(dowalls[1,],nr=1) #force dimensions 
     dowalls<-dowalls[-1,,drop=FALSE]
     treerow <- 1 #current row of tree we're looking at
     while ( treerow <= nrow(tree) ) {
         #only examine the first 'column' of the dist() matrix 'cause those are the
         # distances from the tree[] endpoints
         touch <- c( which(dist(rbind(tree[treerow,1:2],dowalls[,1:2]) )[1:nrow(dowalls)]==0),  which(dist(rbind(tree[treerow,1:2],dowalls[,3:4]) )[1:nrow(dowalls)]==0), which(dist(rbind(tree[treerow,3:4],dowalls[,1:2]) )[1:nrow(dowalls)]==0), which(dist(rbind(tree[treerow,3:4],dowalls[,3:4]) )[1:nrow(dowalls)]==0) )
         if(length(touch) ) {
            tree <- rbind(tree,dowalls[c(touch),])
            dowalls <- dowalls[-c(touch),,drop=FALSE] 
            }
    # now be careful: want to track the row of tree[] we're working with AND
    # track how many rows there currently are in tree[]
        treerow <- treerow + 1 
    } #end of while treerow <= nrow 
    treelist[[treecnt]]<-tree
    treecnt <- treecnt + 1 
} #end ; all walls have been classified
```